# DOMDocument removes the <body> tag and its contents

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I'm having some issues with scraping a site. The HTML when returned is perfectly fine. I can copy it from the site manually and store it in a variable, and `saveHTML()` returns the entire HTML. But when injected into DOMDocument directly from the site programmatically, it for some reason removes the entire `<body>` tag rendering it useless so I can't query it with `XPath`. Does anyone know why this may happen? Only thing it keeps is the `<head>` and the contents within.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

echo htmlentities($dom->saveHTML());
```

The HTML that DOMDocument screws up looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE">

       ....

   </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the document have a `<body>`? :) Just asking because I tried the same piece of code here with a HTML document and the result was fine.

Comment: @WilliamJanoti Yes of course it has, why would I then be bothered by this problem?

Comment: Please show a minimal, but complete sample of your PHP code that people can use to reproduce this problem. Also, say which HTML page you are talking about and link to it.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I can't really link to the page because it contains sensitive data. The PHP code I posted is what I'm using to create the DOM object.

Comment: Then you should not expect anyone to be able to help I'm afraid. Problems that cannot be reproduced cannot be solved. Instead of linking to the original, sensitive page you could of course try to reproduce the issue with any other document and post that.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I solved the problem. Wasn't easy though ;)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the culprit to why DOMDocument was choking on the fetched HTML. It apparently contained two `NUL` (ASCII code `0x00`) characters which are forbidden according the official HTML specification. Replacing them prior to loading the HTML solved the problem.